# Admin not loading _toHtml(): Cannot load resource

Tags: magento2, admin

I have installed Magento 2.4.1, Frontend pages are working fine but while loading admin page it is throwing exceptions.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning:
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar::_toHtml(): Cannot load
> resource element '0' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar.php
> on line 114

I have tried running the following commands:
bin/magneto setup:upgrade

bin/magneto setup:di:compile

bin/magneto setup:static-content:deploy

also tried clearing cache and re indexing etc.

Please guide me to fix this.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Shivani Yes, as I remember this is due to wrong php version. Please check and confirm if itworks for you.

Comment: This is happening for me in MAC. Also, I have the correct PHP version and INTL configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing lines 114 and 115 to

```
    $this->assign('am', $this->encoder->encode($localeData['calendar']['gregorian']['AmPmMarkers'][0]));
    $this->assign('pm', $this->encoder->encode($localeData['calendar']['gregorian']['AmPmMarkers'][1]));
```

(i.e. removing the quotes around 0 and 1) solved the problem for me (on Magento 2.4.2 on Windows with intl ICU version 66.1).